# JMeter non gui mode doesn't print header line for csv file

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems

I encountered strange thing when running JMeter script from command line. All properties in Jmeter.properties are set correctly to print header in csv file. i.e.

`jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true`

If I do following it doesn't print csv header.

`> result.jtl && ./bin/jmeter.sh -n -t PerfJdbc.jmx -l result.jtl`

But if I do following instead it does:

`rm -rf result.jtl && ./bin/jmeter.sh -n -t PerfJdbc.jmx -l result.jtl`

Difference is how I reset the file content. Emptying file using `> result.jtl` introduces the issue but if I instead just remove the file it works. Am I missing something very basic here about filesystem? anyone please explain the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in the latter case the file **exists** therefore JMeter doesn't add the header just in case your target it to append new results to the existing .jtl results file.

Actually you don't even need the .jtl file deletion or truncation interim step, you can launch JMeter like:

```
./jmeter -n -t -f PerfJdbc.jmx -l result.jtl
```

> **-f**, **--forceDeleteResultFile**
>
> force delete existing results files before start the test

References:

- [JMeter: Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)